# Text Selection jumps to top

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

I have some absolutely positioned divs with some text node inside it .
When I try to do text selection which span across divs selection jumps to the page .
For example in the  in this sample code http://jsfiddle.net/SQ39f/
when I try to select "second line" selection jumps to the top when my cursor is in between "second" and "line".

```
<div>
<div style="position:absolute; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; left: 422.178px; top: 10.523px; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.04982, 1); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;" dir="ltr">FIRST</div>
<div style="position:absolute; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; left: 530.61px; top: 10.523px; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.05114, 1); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;" dir="ltr">LINE</div>
<div style="position:absolute; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; left: 422.178px; top: 30.523px; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.04982, 1); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;" dir="ltr">SECOND</div>
<div style="position:absolute; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; left: 530.61px; top: 30.523px; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.05114, 1); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;" dir="ltr">LINE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selection applies to the element (if selectable) the mouse is over.

When the mouse is between the first and second word in the second line, the element under cursor is the parent DIV holding the absolutely positioned DIVs.

Comment: Ok .Is there a CSS available trick to make this selection smooth ?

Comment: I thought turning off `pointer-events` for the parent and overriding them for the children should do the trick. Unfortunately it doesn't. :-(

Comment: I suggest you fill up the spaces *between* the words in a line with empty spans or so, so that the selection event does not propagate to the parent div.

Comment: Inserting empty span didnt work for me .Do i need to compute the width ?

Comment: Yeah, the thing to ensure is that in the middle of a selection process, the mouse is always over one of the children, and never directly over the parent.

Answer (score 0):

This question is (or is very nearly) duplicated by your other post, [Text selection flickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893756/text-selection-flickers/).

However, to provide a more accurate resolution to this topic for anyone else wishing to solve a similar problem I will link [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893756/text-selection-flickers/25271681#25271681) and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ39f/10/).

The jumping issue described here is fixed via a combination of `div width` stretching (it seems the magic number in this case is `81px`) and a spacer div between each text 'line'.