# Text selection flickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I make text selection smooth for the where divs are laid out in the following format http://jsfiddle.net/SQ39f/2/.
You can see that during selection process selection highlight jumps to the top and flickers.
Try selecting text "SECOND LINE"
Also not that I dont have control over position,left and top style properties as they are set by third party .I can just add additional styles.

```
<div>
<div style="position:absolute ;left: 100.178px; top: 10.523px">FIRST</div>
<div style="position:absolute;left: 180.61px; top: 10.523px;">LINE</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left: 100.178px; top: 30.523px;">SECOND</div>
<div style="position:absolute;  left: 190.61px; top: 30.523px;" >LINE</div>
```

Comment: Why are you positioning text absolute? Want you want to do?

Comment: Yeah, don't put them in separate `div`s. Of course selection is going to be odd; you've separated them on the page.

Comment: @estshy they are third party generated styles .This tool renders a PDF document thats whay this divs are absolutly positioned .

Comment: Without manipulating code structure, I don't think you can do anything with this behavior.

Comment: @estshy assuming that I will override this .What can be done to achieve smooth text selection functionality ?Is there a way i can stretch the divs ?

Comment: I dont understend what result u want, if u want to select second line as jQuery, u can put that 2 divs in one with class a2, than $(".a2")

Comment: _“This tool renders a PDF document”_ – then how is how this behaves as HTML in a browser an issue here?

Comment: @CBroe if the user will try to do some text selection the selection will jump to the top whenever mouse pointer moves over a region which does not have div .

Comment: Are you able to manipulate any aspects of the text display? If you can't alter the html, can you change the css at all? The selection problem comes from the gap between the 'SECOND' and 'LINE' divs; if you can extend the divs to remove that gap (e.g. add padding to the 'SECOND' div), the selection will be smooth.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I've come up with:

HTML-

```
<div>
    <div class="tag" style="position:absolute;left:100.178px;top:10.523px;">FIRST</div>
    <div class="line" style="position:absolute;left:180.61px;top:10.523px;">LINE</div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="tag" style="position:absolute;left:100.178px;top:30.523px;">SECOND</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:160.61px;top:30.523px;display:none;" >&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>
    <div class="line" style="position:absolute;left:180.61px;top:30.523px;" >LINE</div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.tag {
    width:81px;
    height:18px;
}
.line {
    padding-right:100px;
    height:18px;
}
```

Setting `height:18px;` normalizes the selection height; setting `width:81px` bridges the gap between the left and right `div`s just enough so they touch, but do not overlap. The `div` full of non-breaking spaces is not needed, so I set its `display` to `none`. If you can, remove that element entirely.

Preventing selection of the second line from jumping to the first is done by adding a `div` between the first "LINE" `div` and the "SECOND" `div`. This acts as a spacer between the lines, so when the selection jumps to the previous `div` you don't see any graphical change.

`padding-right:100px` extends the `div`'s box and allows you to drag your cursor further to the right of the text and still maintain selection of that line. I wouldn't advise setting it below `10px`, otherwise you may get flickering on the last character of the first line when selecting the second line.

This method should work for any number of lines, so long as you repeat the classes correctly and add in the spacer `div` between each `div.line` and the following `div.tag`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ39f/10/

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment about extending the divs to remove the gap, here's some css you could add to the page in your example.

Set the width of the divs to cover the gap between the left- and right-hand columns. I've zeroed the border, margin, and padding, and set the line height to make things look neat:

```
div { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 18px; }
div div { width: 81px; height: 18px; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ39f/18/

If you know what the text looks like in advance (e.g. if you've got a table of results), this is the easiest option.

If the lines are not uniformly laid out, you can use javascript to calculate the appropriate width for the divs -- iterate through the lefthand divs, subtract the 'left' position from that of the next sibling. This is fairly easily achieved with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to replace the absolute positioning and reposition as relative.  I did this using the following jQuery but it could be done in straight javascript if necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[style*="position"]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.css('position') === 'absolute') {
            var offset = $this.offset();
            $this.css('position', 'relative');
            $this.offset(offset);
        }
    });
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k24p90jh/1/

Answer (score -1):

Try out this solustion
[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/k9pr98n8/1/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>FIRST</td>
        <td>LINE</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>SECOND</td>
        <td>LINE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It renders/displays the same way, just different code, and fixed your highlighting problem..
tables act like regular div tags, just make sure that you have no border (border="0"). Hope this helped =)

Answer (score -2):

First of all you would need to get rid of `position: absolute` to improve selecting, anyway I guess that it isn't possible? In that case only solution that comes to my mind is creating white filling of ' ` between next part of text

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ39f/3/